# In android studio 2 buttons looks fine on a preview, but on actuall device it's outside screen

Tags: android, layout

Hello I have made simple calculator app for Android. It all works well.
But my next step was to implement layout for landscape mode. After an hour I've came out with nice layout, everything looks fine... until I run the app on device (Huawei P8 Lite).

This is how it looks in the Designer/Preview:
[image: This is how it looks in the Designer/Preview:]

And here's how it's like running on my device:
[image: And here's how it's like running on my device]

I have no idea what might be wrong. I've made a couple of layouts before and didn't have such issue. Does anyone know what might cause the bug?

This is my XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.8">

        <me.grantland.widget.AutofitLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".30"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/textBox1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|bottom|right"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />
        </me.grantland.widget.AutofitLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bracketLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="("
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/three"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/plus" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bracketRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=")"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/bracketLeft"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/equals"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/minus" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button27"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="^"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button26"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bracketRight" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/one"
            style="@style/appButtonMaterial_land"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="1"
            android:typeface="normal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/four" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/backspace"
            style="@style/appButtonMaterial_land"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_backspace_black_24dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/multiple"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/multiple"
            style="@style/appButtonMaterial_land"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="X"
            android:typeface="normal"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/divide"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/two"
            style="@style/appButtonMaterial_land"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="2"
            android:typeface="normal"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/one"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/five" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/three"
            style="@style/appButtonMaterial_land"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="3"
            android:typeface="normal"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/two"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/six" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/four"
            style="@style/appButtonMaterial_land"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="4"
            android:typeface="normal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seven" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/six"
            style="@style/appButtonMaterial_land"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="6"
            android:typeface="normal"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/five"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nine" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/divide"
            style="@style/appButtonMaterial_land"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="/"
            android:typeface="normal"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/nine"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clear"
            style="@style/appButtonMaterial_land"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="C"
            android:typeface="normal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/equals"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/minus"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/backspace"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/seven"
            style="@style/appButtonMaterial_land"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="7"
            android:typeface="normal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/eight"
            style="@style/appButtonMaterial_land"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="8"
            android:typeface="normal"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/seven"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/five"
            style="@style/appButtonMaterial_land"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="5"
            android:typeface="normal"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/four"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/eight" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plus"
            style="@style/appButtonMaterial_land"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="+"
            android:typeface="normal"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/six"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divide" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/minus"
            style="@style/appButtonMaterial_land"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="-"
            android:typeface="normal"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/plus"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/multiple" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nine"
            style="@style/appButtonMaterial_land"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="9"
            android:typeface="normal"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/eight"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dot"
            style="@style/appButtonMaterial_land"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="."
            android:typeface="normal"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/zero"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/three" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/equals"
            style="@style/appButtonMaterial_land"
            android:layout_height="97dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="="
            android:typeface="normal"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="103dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button27"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,1:1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/zero"
            style="@style/appButtonMaterial_land"
            android:layout_width="176dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="0"
            android:typeface="normal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/two" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button26"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-1dp"
            android:text="%"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/dot"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bracketLeft" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You're using a ConstraintLayout, and missing a few constraints, probably

Comment: Also, the preview defaults to a Nexus4 device, I believe, so you should change that if you want to see the preview on different screen sizes

Comment: It doesn't matter if I use Nexus4 or 5 or any other in preview. In preview it's always displayed properly. And about missing constraints, which do I miss? I can't add more to buttons "backspace", "C" and "equals", simply Designer doesn't allow me to add more.

Comment: Then it's the constraint layout. Remove `tools:layout_editor_` properties from the XML and then look at the preview

Comment: I removed those properties and the preview showed what I see on the device. But now, how can I adjust those button? If I move them with Designer, problem occurs again or buttons get crazy all over the screen :<

Comment: ok thanks man for the reply, it finnally worked dunno how but it's almost okay now. I only need to make the equals button twice high as others

Comment: When you move them around on the preview of a ConstraintLayout, that doesn't mean that's where they will be on the screen. *this is only to make editing easier*... https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html